# Why google map v2 suddenly crashed by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an issue that caused by NullPointerException. **App starts crashing today when i'm trying to do mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);** but yesterday it was fine. I just change my layout file to another (similar) with another name. 
Here's exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>        Process: com.parking.android, PID: 17585
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>                                                                            at maps.G.a.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.V.N.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.D.e.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.D.p.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at maps.ad.R.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at uo.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66)
>                                                                            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
>                                                                            at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzbow(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at
>   com.parking.android.map.fragment.MapsFragment.initMap(MapsFragment.java:105)
>                                                                            at
>   com.parking.android.map.fragment.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:92)
>                                                                            at
>   com.parking.android.base_arch.fragment.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:48)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5550)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)

And here is some of my code with mapView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(savedInstanceState);
    initMap(savedInstanceState);
}
private void initMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMapView.getExtendedMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1000, this);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: ", e);
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    mMapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    presenter.getParkings();
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (mMap == null)
        return;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    try {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is with some list u have used ... please make sure that u have done null check before the code list.length() is written

Comment: @RissmonSuresh Ok, but why app isn't crash on the other device?

Comment: @RissmonSuresh And list.length() is not written anywhere.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, it only happens on a device with 5.1.1 and Resurrecition Remix rom. I don't know what to do neither.

Comment: Probably this issue is not amongst your worries now but, you're calling `mMapView.onResume()` twice. Was that a mistake or was it really in your app's code and you're doing in on purpose?

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT 2: This bug is solved on newest versions of Google Maps.**

**EDIT: A user has pointed that this bug is happening also in 7.0 devices, so keep in mind that you may change `android:maxSdkVersion="22"` to an appropiate Sdk version.**

The problem is only happening in 5.1.1 devices with custom roms like Resurrection Remix. I don't know the reason, but you can solve it adding this to your manifest, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39696819/4208583 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724556/4208583.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: Not just with custom roms. But the fix does work exactly as that.

Comment: I can confirm that its not just 5.1, its also 7.0 , we've been able to recreate it

Comment: why does it have to be max sdk version 22? Does that mean if the OS is beyond Lollipop that reading and writing to external storage won't work anymore? Nougat is at least sdk version 24.

Comment: @chitgoks this is not necessary anymore if you use newest versions of Google Maps.

Comment: It still exists

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue in Maps V2

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10569

Answer (score 0):

I solved it calling `mapView.on~()` withint every lifecycle method *MapView* implements. I wasn't calling it during `onPause()`, but after that, it worked. I'm also calling it in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.