# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using `GoogleMap` in android app using `Android Studio`. It was working fine and don't know why suddenly it stopped working. minSdkVersion is 15 and targetSdkVersion is 24. Please check my below code and help me to come out of this :

**XML:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Gridle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.24.3'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
}
```

**Java:**

```
    public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {
          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
          }
    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**Error:**

It is giving error in xml at `<fragment`, error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file : Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: Is your Activity extends `FragmentAcitvity` or a Normal `Activity`?

Comment: @MD, It extends `v4 Fragment`.

Comment: What error is throwing ?

Comment: @Piyush, It is giving error in xml at <fragment, error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file : Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Change it to `MapFragment`.

Comment: use MapFragment rather than SupportMapFragment

Comment: You test in device or emulator ?

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya, device

Comment: Please make sure that your fragment is v4 or not which you extend it in java file

Comment: @JeetenParmar U did what i told?

Comment: Try `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: I'm getting the same error since update to 9.6.1, don't know what to do.

Comment: It's only not working in Android 5.1.1

Comment: @Grender, yes, right. It is no working just on Android 5.1.1. I tested on other devices and it is working fine. Did u find any solution ?

Comment: @Piyush, yes I tried and still same error.

Comment: @JeetemParmar Nope, still not working

Comment: @Grender, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding permission in manifest, It solved my issue. Check below code :

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="24" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="24" />
```

Comment: It's working, but why? I think `android:maxSdkVersion="22"` is most appropriate. By the way, It seems slower than before, like it gets stuck for some ms.

Comment: @Grender, I removed `maxSdkVersion` and it is working fine. No need of it.

Comment: Where did you get this solution?

Comment: @Grender, I don't remember exactly but I was searching on google and tried this also and It solved my issue. Did it solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes, it solved my issue, but it seems to be a weird workaround, hope it's a bug and it gets solved by Google.

Comment: @Grender, yes, it is bug in play service library.

Answer (score 0):

Please use getMapAsync.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

Comment: It is giving error in xml at `<fragment`, error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file : Error inflating class fragment`

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` add:

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In XML add `context`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.___yourPackageName______"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context="com.___yourPackageName______"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getChildFragmentManager` is used in Nested Fragments. The fragment you've used is not a child of another fragment. Use `getSupportFragmentManager` or `getFragmentManager` for fragment transactions.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag) for more information.

In addition, I would like to mention that You're integrating an old Maps API. Try the latest one https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes second time, you need to destroy it.

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapfragmentnamehere).commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    setUpMap(googleMap);

}
```