# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an application which uses google map APIs. In my application i want to show google map and set marker on my current location by getting my device latitude and longitude from GPS. In beginning when i was implement following code that works well, i test it on my device but after installing 15 or 20 times on my mobile device it starts crashing automatically although i didn't do anything on that activity.

The logs which are showing me android studio are following

**Logs**

```
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication, PID: 9110
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
09-24 16:30:43.414 9110-9110/com.example.nabeelfarooq.mapsnavapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.Console;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    public static double latitude;
    public static double longitude;
    private Button button;
    private LatlngAdapter databasedata = null;
    final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
                i.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            int requestCode = 10;

            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = fm.getMap();

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;

            }
            else {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        onMapReady(mMap);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    public void turnGPSOn() {
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this);
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Enable it?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
/** Here it's leading to GPS setting options*/
                                    Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                                }
                            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    //obtain the supportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){

        if(mGoogleApiClient==null){
            mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager1=getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(supportMapFragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().hide(supportMapFragment).commit();
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                //fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map,supportMapFragment).commit();
            // Handle the home action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,About_us_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Contact_us_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Rate_app) {
           Intent intent=new Intent(this,TipsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap =googleMap;
        LatLng lahore=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("lahore").snippet("lahore HQ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position(sydney));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        LatLng lahore=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("You are here").snippet("lahore").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position(lahore));
       // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lahore));
    }
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
        Log.d("CONNECTED", "I am connected");
        mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation!=null){
            Log.d("Latitude",String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.d("Longitude",String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    static String latString =Double.toString(latitude);
    static String lonString =Double.toString(longitude);
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/abc_action_bar_up_container"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Me Somewhere"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#5368ed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: Your actual error...  `NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

Comment: You are getting NullpointerException as cricket_007 had commented. Somewhere you are getting length of array , which is not even initialized.   Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: Im getting the same error since google maps update to 9.6.1, don't know what to do.

Comment: It's only not working in Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: A user has pointed that this bug is happening also in 7.0 devices, so keep in mind that you may change `android:maxSdkVersion="22"` to an appropiate Sdk version.**

The problem is only happening in 5.1.1 devices with custom roms like Resurrection Remix. I don't know the reason, but you can solve it adding this to your manifest, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39696819/4208583.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: [Fabric](https://fabric.io/) [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) said my app has crashed in one of the users who has Galaxy S5 (OS: 5.1.1), too!

Answer (score -1):

Remove action bar in manifest by specifying NoActionBar theme

Comment: Could you explain this answer in more detail?

Comment: Change your activity theme

      
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: Sure, how does this allow the layout to be inflated though?

Comment: When we use Toolbar instead of ActionBar, we have to hide it by specifying NoActionBar them. let me know if this solution works otherwise post your activity_main.xml

Comment: I didn't post the question. I am simply asking how this resolves the error in the post. There is a null pointer in the stacktrace and changing the actionbar shouldn't fix that